# Do method definitions reside in heap memory?

Tags: java, jvm

I know that when we allocate memory using new statement, that memory is allocated on the heap. Say my class looks like this

```
public class Car{
int prop1;
int prop2;

void method1(){
}

void method2(){}

}
```

Say in my main method, I have a statement `Car c = new Car();` Here variable c is stored in stack memory, while new will allocate memory on heap.

Since prop1, and pro2 are instance variable, they are also stored on the heap, right?

I would like to where are method1, and method2 stored wrt main memory?